# Troubleshooting React App Deployment on Fly.io: 503 Error

Tags: reactjs, docker, devops, vite, fly

Im looking into deploying a full stack application on fly.io. I've deployed the server side code which is written in NodeJS on fly.io. However I cant figure out how to deploy the react-app on fly.io.

An approach I tried was to use a vite project and then dockerize it and then deploy it on fly.io. This successfully deploys a static site however when I try to send a get request to my server endpoints it fails:
`chrome-error://chromewebdata/:1     Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 503 ()`
However when I comment it out, it loads the static site with ease.

This is my App.tsx:

```js
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Box } from "@mui/material";
import { ClimbingBoxLoader } from "react-spinners";
import MainLayout from "./layouts/mainLayout";

function App () {
  const [backendData, setBackendData] = useState<any>({});
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const proxy = "https://xyz-server.fly.dev";

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(`${proxy}/api`)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      setBackendData(data);
      setLoading(false);
    });
  }, []);


  return (
    <>
      {loading ? (
        <Box
          display="flex"
          justifyContent="center"
          alignItems="center"
          height="100vh"
        >
          <Box display="flex" alignItems="center">
            <ClimbingBoxLoader color="#4318FF" size={40} aria-label="Loading Spinner" />
          </Box>
        </Box>
      ) : (
        <MainLayout backendData={backendData.data} />
      )}
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

The example scenario I mentioned that runs has this code:

```js
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
function App () {
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('hello');
  }, []);
  return (
    <p> This is the App </p>  
  );
}
export default App;
```

This is my server.ts in the NodeJS project:

```js
import * as dotenv from 'dotenv';
import express, { Express } from 'express';
import { processGoogleSheetsData } from './utility/googleExtracter/extractGoogleSheets';
import { google } from 'googleapis';
import fs from 'fs';
import path from 'path';

dotenv.config();
const PORT: number = parseInt(process.env.PORT as string, 10) || 9001;
const app: Express = express();
// For cors
const allowedOrigins = [
  'https://xyz-app.fly.dev',
  'http://localhost:3000'
];
// Returns the client with the data in the googleSheet.json
app.get("/api", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    .....

    // Assuming csvDataMap and competencyGroup are extracted from dataFromJSON
    const responseData = {
      .....
    };

    const origin = req.headers.origin || '';
    if (allowedOrigins.includes(origin)) {
      res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', origin);
    }
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Authorization');

    res.status(200).json({
      data: responseData,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    res.status(500).json({
      message: "Internal Server Error",
      Error: error
    });
  }
});

// listener
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server Started On Port ${PORT}`);
});
```

The server runs fine when I visit the endpoint from the browser its returning everything correctly.
I've tested the docker container locally, it runs fine. These are my config files:

fly.toml:

```
app = "test-cr-app"
primary_region = "sin"
kill_signal = "SIGINT"
kill_timeout = "5s"

[env]

[experimental]
  auto_rollback = true

[build]

[[services]]
  protocol = "tcp"
  internal_port = 8080
  processes = ["app"]

  [[services.ports]]
    port = 80
    handlers = ["http"]
    force_https = true

  [[services.ports]]
    port = 443
    handlers = ["tls", "http"]
  [services.concurrency]
    type = "connections"
    hard_limit = 25
    soft_limit = 20

  [[services.tcp_checks]]
    interval = "15s"
    timeout = "2s"
    grace_period = "1s"
```

vite.config:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  server: {
    host: true,
    strictPort: true,
    port: 8080
  }
})
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:17-alpine as build
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json .
RUN npm i
COPY . .
RUN npm run build
CMD [ "npm", "run", "dev" ]
```

Im not quite sure what Im doing wrong, In my browser console this is the error mssg that I get

```
chrome-error://chromewebdata/:1     Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 503 ()
```

OR

```
[plugin:vite:esbuild] The service is no longer running
/app/src/App.tsx
    at /app/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:826:29
    at sendRequest (/app/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:699:14)
    at start (/app/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:824:9)
    at Object.transform2 [as transform] (/app/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:889:5)
    at /app/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:2194:77
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Object.transform (/app/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:2194:36)
    at transform (/app/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:2027:62)
    at transformWithEsbuild (file:///app/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-df561101.js:13910:30)
    at async TransformContext.transform (file:///app/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-df561101.js:13984:32)
    at async Object.transform (file:///app/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-df561101.js:44283:30)
    at async loadAndTransform (file:///app/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-df561101.js:54950:29
```

OR

```
/src/main.tsx:1     Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 ()
```